# How to know if their is change in call log using contentOberser.

Tags: android, calllog, contentobserver

I am new to android development.
I want to monitor the changes occurred in the call log.My code is fetching all the call history until the last recent call log.when I run my app it again fetches all the logs including the newest one but I want only the latest changes. Please guide me how can I achieve this with **contentOberser** ? Please help. this is my code

```
private void conatctDetails()
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Cursor c1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        sb.append("Contact details:");
        try
        {
        while(c1.moveToNext())
          {
              String id = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
              String name =c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
              String timesContacted =c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED));
              String lastTimeContacted =c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED));

              String number="";
             // String number =c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
              if(id==null||name==null)
                  continue;
              Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                if(cur==null)
                    continue;
                number = "";
                while(cur.moveToNext())
                {
                    number = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    sb.append("\n Contact Number:--"+number);
                }

              sb.append("\n Contact Name:--"+name+"\n Contact ID:--"+id+"\n Last Time Contacted:--"+lastTimeContacted+"\n Total Time Contacted:--"+timesContacted);

        sb.append("\n----------------------------");
          }
        //c1.close();
         contact.setText(sb);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
        finally
        {
            c1.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: use ContentResolver.registerContentObserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is an `Intent` that is fired on an incoming call you could get your app to respond by using a `BroadcastReceiver` and create an `IntentFilter` in your manifest.

Or just query the provider when your app launches...

`ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` is a `TelephonyManager` intent you can listen for and check if it is `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING`.